# WP query filter posts based on url arguments

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a set of wordpress postst that have various metafields. I'm trying to filter through these posts depending on the arguments given in a url. For example.

```
www.example.com/?artist=franksinatra&mood=
```

Should bring up all posts with frank sinatra as the artist field, but ignoring the mood field because its blank. That works fine. But I'd like to narrow my search even further. So when I add additional arguments such as:

```
www.example.com/?artist=franksinatra&mood=sad
```

All posts with that field combination should show up. Here's the beginning of my loop that allows me to search using one argument but not additional ones. Thank you.

```
<?php
$queryArtist = $_GET['artist'];
$queryMood = $_GET['mood'];
$paged = get_query_var('paged');
    $loop = new WP_Query( array(
    'posts_per_page' => 5,
    'post_type' => 'catalog',
    'paged' => $paged,
    'order_by' => 'ASC',
     'meta_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'OR',
        array(
            'key' => 'artist',
            'value' => $queryArtist,
            'compare' => '=',
        )
    )
    )
            );
    while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>
```

Comment: What's actually being returned?

Answer (score 0):

you can add additional queries like this:

```
'meta_query' => array(
    'relation' => 'AND',
    array(
        'key' => 'artist',
        'value' => $queryArtist,
        'compare' => '=',
    ),
    array(
        'key' => 'mood',
        'value' => $queryMood,
        'compare' => '=',
    )
)
```

by switching the relation from "OR" to "AND" both conditions have to be true